# Fancybox image size causes image to fly up from bottom of screen

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm afraid I can't upload an example at the moment but I have a problem with Fancybox.

To reproduce the problem, donwload the zip file from [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), then in the Image Gallery example increase the height of the image that appears when you click the second thumbnail with an image editor. It will work fine when you click previous and next through the images if you haven't scrolled the page but if you put in a lot of `<br />` tags increasing the length of the page then scoll down to launch the gallery again, when you click through them the second large image that opens flies up from the bottom of the screen instead of resizing from the previous image.

So in other words the large versions of images all have to be the same size for it to work properly. How can I make Fancybox work with different-size images?

Temporary fix is to change the default changeSpeed and changeFade in jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js...

```
changeSpeed:    0,
changeFade: 300,
```

Comment: Fork it on there Github if u think its a bug

Comment: I will do. Definitely a bug. Updated above post with temporary fix. Hope it helps someone.